# Visual Studio 2017 - Insert Final NewLine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, newline

Is there a feature / extension for Visual Studio 2017 to automatically end files with a newline?

I'm looking for a similar option as with [VS Code's "Insert Final NewLine"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12076)

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a feature called "EditorConfig" that allows placing a file in specific locations that allow to set various configurations about how to format files. In particular, one of them is to end files with a new line. To activate it, create a file named `.editorconfig` in the root of your solution and add this content:

```
root = true

[*]
insert_final_newline = true
```

To apply a trailing newline to every single file in the solution.
Look at the [full documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2017) of the feature for details and other options.

Note that such formating actually happens when you format the whole document, not on its own as you write.

For previous versions of Visual Studio, there is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfigTeam.EditorConfig) that does the very same thing. It's bundled begining with VS2017.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro! I'm new to `.editorconfig` but I really like using it. Never knew it can automatically edit files as well. Thought it was just for code style. Good to know! :)

Comment: Hmmm.. works in VSCode!  Does not Visual Studio for Mac (17.6 Preview).